# Regex replace in sublimetext2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I would like to use regex (preferably in sublimetext2) to replace the following:

```
<audio id="element29">
<source src="../../audio/sounds/01/mysound.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>
<source src="../../audio/sounds/01/mysound.wav" type='audio/wav'>
</audio>
```

with this:

```
<?php audioButton("../../audio/sounds/01/mysound","mysound"); ?>
```

My regex skills are nonexistent, so I'll be most grateful if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what:

```
<audio id="element\d+">\s*(?:<source src="([^"]+/([^/]+))\.(mp3|wav)" type=[^>]+>\s*){2}</audio>
```

Replace with:

```
<?php audioButton("$1","$2"); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I have one more question: Sometimes the part after element is not just a number. For example, I have something like <audio id="element6_slx">

Comment: I think I found it: \d+\D+

Comment: Thanks again! It would only have taken me 10 years to figure that out!

Comment: Hi Poke. I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269122/replace-using-regex-in-sublimetext2. I hope you can help me again.